# What values are pushed onto stack during a function call?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to modify the value of local variable through another called function, but I am not able to figure out what all values pushed onto the stack are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fun()
{
  int i; 
  int *p=&i; 
  int j; 
  for(j=0;*(p+j)!=10;j++);
  printf("%d",j);
  /* Stack Frame size is j int pointers. */ 
  *(p+j)=20; 
}    

main()
{
  int i=10;
  fun();
  printf("\n %d \n",i);
}
```

How exactly does `j` in `fun()` equal to `12`? I am trying to understand what values are pushed onto stack. More specifically, can we change the value of `i` which is in `main()` without using a `for` loop in `fun()` and is it possible to predict the value of `j` inside `fun()`?

Comment: This should address your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: It could be simpler. 

`void fun(int* ip)
{
   *ip = 20;
}
int main()
{
   int i = 10;
   fun(&i);
}`

Comment: @RSahu: The purpose of question is to understand what values are pushed onto stack

Comment: @DickTanner That question is at best distantly related to this one.

Comment: "I am trying to understand what values are pushed onto stack." -- To do that, look at the assembler output, and/or the documentation of your compiler's calling sequence.

Comment: a variable doesn't necessarily have to be on stack

Comment: @debonair: Looking around the web for information on the call stack and calling convention might help

Comment: Maybe you're running into a different `10`. Try a different number like `12345`.

Comment: @ooga Not if the OP's program prints 20. Too bad the OP didn't say.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, this question is based on several misconceptions about the C language and what one can expect of non-conforming programs.

Comment: @JimBalter Good point! When I ran it it still printed `10`. Changing the original number to `12345` resulted in the expected `20` for `i` in `main` and `14` for `j` in `fun`.

Comment: @ooga You changed it to `i=12345` and it printed `i` as 20? That would be strange.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes I also tried to print i in main and it prints 20. The value of j is undefined as if we add one more variable in main() before calling fun() the value of j changes

Comment: @Gopi You got 20 but I doubt that you changed `i=10` to `i=12345`. "The value of j is undefined" -- the whole program has undefined behavior, so yes of course the C standard does not define what `j`s value will be. "if we add one more variable in main() before calling fun() the value of j changes" -- well of course; that's the whole point of the OP's exercise.

Comment: @JimBalter How would that be strange? `fun` scanned the stack until it found the value `12345` and then changed it to `20`.

Comment: first the parameters are pushed on the stack, in reverse order, by the caller: then the PC is pushed on the stack, by the hardware; then local variables of the called function are pushed on the stack, in reverse order, by the called function.

Comment: @ooga It's not strange if you changed it to `i=12345` **and** you changed it to `for(j=0;*(p+j)!=12345;j++);`, but that wasn't clear.

Comment: @user3629249 Not necessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have to access local variables from other function calls, I think you had better redesign your code.

Theoretically, you can direct to modify the `i` of `main()` in `fun()` if you can completely understand how the compilers deal with the activation records of function calls on the run-time stack. You can read "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" for details( [http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-Edition/dp/0321486811](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) )

[image]

The value of j depends on the run-time stack address between the `int i;` in the fun() and `int i = 10;` in main() . In this case, when fun() is called, their relative distance on stack is just 12. That is why the `j` is 12. So the `*(p + j) = 20;` actually changed the `i` of the main(). If you change your code by adding `int a = 14;` as following, you will find the value of `j` changed for the activation record on the run-time stack has been changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun()
{
  int i;
  int *p=&i;
  int j;
  for(j=0;*(p+j)!=10;j++);
  printf("%d",j);
  /* Stack Frame size is j int pointers. */
  *(p+j)=20;
}

main()
{
  int i=10;
  int a=14;  /* add this for example to change the relative address i in the main and i in the fun*/
  fun();
  printf("\n %d \n",i);
}
```

Comment: "in the fun i will be initialized by 0 if you don not explicitly assign something to it" -- no it won't. The value is undefined and in most implementations will be whatever junk is in the stack location or register used to hold `i`. if it happens to be 10, then j will be 0. The rest of what you wrote is too convoluted for me to parse.

Comment: @JimBalter: Yes, you are right. I'll try my best to express my idea well and I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here in `fun()`

- i contains 0 or some garbage value
- p contains the addresses of i

In the for loop j is initially 0 and the for loop will run until the value in the address `p+j !=10` and j is incremented.

So there is no way to correctly predict the outcome of the print in `fun()`

and also before getting out of the `fun()` you are trying to assign 20 to the memory location `p=j` where  j could be any `value [0,+infinity)` no way of telling correctly

meanwhile the print func in main() will display value of local i that is 10  that is if the address of this i in main() in not equal `to p+j`

Comment: You're missing the whole point of the OP's code. It assigns a stack address to `p`, then searches the stack until it finds the value `10`, which presumably gives the offset between local variable `i` in fun and local variable `i` in main ... assuming that both of these variables are on the stack, there is no other instance of `10` on the stack inbetween, and that the stack grows downward.